# Splitting a semicolon-separated string in an Excel function

Tags: string, vba, excel

Is it possible to create an Excel-Function to split a semicolon-separated string to n adjacent cells?

I can create a function which does the opposite (concat the values of n cells via semicolon and put the value into a specific cell), the opposite does not seem to work. Can anyone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's feasible, but you need to create array function which requires to call it as you do with any array function using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Function code:

```
Function SemiColToCells(SemiColStrin As String)

    Dim tmpArr As Variant
        tmpArr = Split(SemiColStrin, ";")

    'Next line creates array function!
    SemiColToCells = tmpArr
End Function
```

Picture of Excel sheet presenting example with correct and incorrect way of calling the function:

[image]

Comment: That's a feasible way, although it's a pity I can't get rid of the array function! So I need to check the number of semicolons to determine the number of cols I need to reserve for the array function.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen, if you don't want to check number of elements in array you need to switch from function into subroutine. Array function is the only one function type which can be used 'as unit' in several cells.